# When is static ip address given?

Tags: ipv4, isp, ip-address

My laptop is connected to the internet via a wifi router. In other words my router is connected to the internet. When i check my ip address via a web service i see that the ip address keeps changing. The ip address that my router gets yesterday is different from what i get today.

1) I am wondering when is a computer given a static ip address?

2) Does one need to pay for a static ip address?

3) Since the point of ip address is to uniquely identify a computer in a network, shouldn't the address be always static? in other words if the address keeps changing then how can it help in uniquely identifying a computer?

I appreciate any help to the above curiosities i have. Thanks a lot!

Comment: An address identifies a certain device at a certain point in time. The network operator decides how and when to assign addresses. Because you are apparently not the operator of that network this question is unfortunately off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two network elements in here to consider.One is your Wifi Router and another one is your Laptop.Currently I don't know whether your setup works in bridged mode or routed mode. In any case from the ISP's perspective providing you a static IP most like would need an additional payment.ISP's BRAS normally will have a Pool of IP address and based on the availability of the users connected to their network they provide these IP address from the pool using PPPOE(PPP) or DHCP(IPOE).

It is not necessary and not practically feasible to provide all the connected devices in Internet with a unique IP due to limitations in IPv4. This is where NAT is coming into picture to help them.If NAT is enabled on your router then your laptop will have a Local IP address (192.168.1.xxx/172.16.xxx.xxx,10.xxx.xxx.xxx).NAT will help the routing of a connected device in Local IP with the help of IP + port number in the local scope of router.

> 1) I am wondering when is a computer given a static ip address?

When the user want to access that PC remotely or that PC will need to act as server in the Internet where the IP is binded to a domain name. Eg. Web Server,Gaming server,DNS server etc.

> 2) Does one need to pay for a static ip address?

Yes,Most likely.However,Some ISP used to provide Static IP free for their premium users or users who pay for higher plans.

> Since the point of ip address is to uniquely identify a computer in a
>   network, shouldn't the address be always static? in other words if the
>   address keeps changing then how can it help in uniquely identifying a
>   computer?

NAT.Nat will help indirectly for a node in the INTERNET to uniquely identify a computer with Public IP+port. However,the public IP will also subject to change if ISP doesnt provide static IP address to your router. This is where people use DynDNS to reach their PC or Modem from internet.